# howto make typescript class instance available using type definition

Tags: typescript

Example of a typescript definition file using [the decomposed class pattern](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files):

```
declare module io {
  interface IOStatic {
    new(name: string): IOInstance;
    name: string;
  }

  interface IOInstance {
    get(): string
  }
}
declare var IO: io.IOStatic;
declare module "IO" {
  export = IO;
}
```

It is used in:

```
/// <reference path='external.d.ts' />
import IO = require('IO');

var x = new IO('John');
```

which works fine.

Question: how can I used the type definition of the IO instance in a type check, e.g.:

```
getName(io: IO): string {
  return io.get();
}
```

error TS4022: Type reference cannot refer to container 'IO'.
Should I export the instance definition too? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on what you're trying to do, so I'm sorry if this isn't answering your question correctly.

The types `io.IOStatic` and `io.IOInstance` are available to you to use like this:

```
import IO = require('IO');

var x = new IO('John'); 

function getName(io: io.IOInstance): string {
    return io.get();
}

getName(x);
```

When you call `new IO('John');`, you get an object of type `io.IOInstance`.

Comment: Sorry the question isn't clear. However, your answer is right on spot. I did not know that the `io` variable was accessible like this. Thanks!